# Ajuda com select e registros repetidos

Tags: sql, select

Tenho um banco de dados postgresql com uma tabela assim:

```
id_usuario | dt_atualizacao | atualizacao | outros_dados
123        | 01-01-2001     | 0           | abc
123        | 01-01-2005     | 1           | abe
123        | 01-01-2012     | 1           | acd
123        | 01-01-2018     | 1           | acc
124        | 01-01-2017     | 0           | acj
124        | 01-01-2018     | 1           | agy
125        | 01-01-2018     | 0           | awe
```

O que ocorre é o seguinte: nesse aplicativo, ao cadastrar um usuário pela primeira vez, ele deixa o campo `atualizacao = 0` e põe a data atual.

mas quando é feita uma atualização nesse cadastro (digamos que mudei o campo `outros_dados`), ao invés de atualizar o registro atual, ele cria um novo registro com nova data e campo `atualização = 1`.

O que preciso é de um select que pegue todos os id de usuário, sem repetir o mesmo e sendo o mais atual. No exemplo acima, eu precisaria do seguinte resultado:

```
id_usuario | dt_atualizacao | atualizacao | outros_dados
123        | 01-01-2018     | 1           | acc
124        | 01-01-2018     | 1           | agy
125        | 01-01-2018     | 0           | awe
```

Alguma dica de como fazer?

obs: antes que venha alguém aqui perguntando "cadê o código", já informo que não tenho ideia de como gerar um select assim, por isso não postei.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A estrutura da tabela não está propriamente "ótima".

Se o que pretende é ter um histórico de atualizações então deverá, como diz e bem o [@Dudaskank](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/61975/dudaskank), é alterar o tipo de dados de `DATE` para `TIMESTAMP` para poder armazenar a hora, minuto e segundo da atualização e assim conseguir pegar na última atualização de forma mais simples e "limpa".

A forma mais ótima de obter as últimas atualizações, tendo em conta a alteração do tipo da coluna `dt_atualizacao`, é utilizando o operador `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT ON (id_usuario) id_usuario
        ,   dt_atualizacao
        ,   outros_dados
FROM        historico
ORDER BY    id_usuario
        ,   dt_atualizacao DESC
```

A tabela `Historico` será a sua tabela com as atualizações.

Comment: é que o sistema nao é meu. eu só estou puxando informações dele, entao nao posso alterar

Comment: A tabela não uma coluna de numeração sequencial? Ou outra qualquer onde se possa fazer uma ordenação correta?

Comment: pior que nao. é um banco de dados enorme (mais de 700 tabelas) que fazem ligação umas com outras, e estou tendo que descobrir qual delas tem as informações que preciso. por enquanto estou com essa aí (e postei apenas um exemplo dela)... mas valeu, vou utilizar seu código de exemplo pra ver se consigo algo por aqui

Comment: O código vai funcionar, mas pode não devolver o resultado 100% correto. Devolve para a última data, mas pode não ser necessariamente a última atualização (porque não temos forma de saber!). Adicionei apenas a questão do `atualizacao = 1`.

Comment: mas creio que pegando a última data dá certo sim, pois nunca é feita mais de uma atualização no mesmo dia. testarei hoje à tarde

Comment: Sendo assim ok, em princípio vai funcionar a 100%!

Comment: No caso, apenas retire a cláusula `where`, pois mantendo ela não irá aparecer a linha com o `125` como desejado inicialmente.

Comment: funcionou corretamente, só estou adaptando aqui e vinculando com outras tabelas. se puder, me esclarece duas coisas: 1. qual a diferença entre `distinct` e `distinct on`? 2. tem algum jeito de nao ordenar primeiro pelo campo do `distinct on`? preciso ordenar por outro campo. abraço

Comment: O `DISTINCT` apenas remove duplicados do resultado, enquanto que o `DISTINCT ON` encontra o primeiro registo num grupo (que é o seu caso). O campo que coloca no `DISTINCT ON` é aquele por onde pretende obter o primeiro registo do grupo, se alterar isso os resultados serão outros! Mas pode "brincar" um bocado com isso, a ver no que dá.

Comment: @Italo Rodrigo, se precisar ordenar por outro campo, aí use a minha resposta. Mais informações sobre o DISTINCT e DISTINCT ON você encontra na documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Answer (score 3):

Alguns pontos para observar:

1. Ao invés de usar um campo do tipo `date`, que parece guardar apenas a data nesse seu exemplo, utilize um `timestamp` ou similar, pois assim se houver mais de uma atualização na mesma data, vai conseguir diferenciar entre elas qual a mais recente.
2. Acredito que não seja necessário essa coluna `atualizacao`. Basta você pegar a maior data para determinado `id` para saber qual o mais recente.

---

#### Atualização 29/08/2018 13:49

Como o autor informou que apenas uma atualização por dia é o que acontece na prática, mesmo usando `date` irá funcionar sem problemas.

Também criei um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/649fb/1) com os dados de exemplo, tanto com a minha solução quanto a solução do colega [@João Martins](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112798/jo%C3%A3o-martins). Por algum motivo, que não entendo muito pra falar a verdade, a minha query acabou sendo mais rápida, então fica a dica (mas a dele é muito mais fácil de ler por um humano, se não precisar de mais velocidade também fica outra dica).

---

Para a query, tente algo assim, onde `historico` é o nome da tabela e `dt_atualizacao` o campo com a data e hora daquele registro:

```
SELECT * FROM historico a WHERE dt_atualizacao=(SELECT MAX(dt_atualizacao) FROM historico b WHERE b.id_usuario=a.id_usuario);
```

Comment: é que o sistema nao é meu. eu só estou puxando informações dele, entao nao posso alterar